# 3.16 LAB: Simple statistics Java

Tags: java

Part 1:
Given 4 integers, output their product and their average, using integer arithmetic.

Ex: If the input is:

8, 10, 5, 4
the output is:

```
1600 6
```

Note: Integer division discards the fraction. Hence the average of 8, 10, 5, 4 is output as 6, not 6.75.

Note: The test cases include four very large input values whose product results in overflow. You do not need to do anything special, but just observe that the output does not represent the correct product (in fact, four positive numbers yield a negative output; wow).

Submit the above for grading. Your program will fail the last test cases (which is expected), until you complete part 2 below.

Part 2:
Also output the product and average, using floating-point arithmetic.

Output each floating-point value with three digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
System.out.printf("%.3f", yourValue);

Ex: If the input is 8, 10, 5, 4, the output is:

```
1600. 6

1600.000 6.750
```

Note that fractions aren't discarded, and that overflow does not occur for the test case with large values.

What I have,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int num4;

        num1 = scnr.nextInt();
        num2 = scnr.nextInt();
        num3 = scnr.nextInt();
        num4 = scnr.nextInt();

        double average_arith = (num1+num2+num3+num4)/4.0;
        double product_arith = num1*num2*num3*num4;

        int result1 = (int) average_arith;
        int result2 = (int) product_arith;

        System.out.printf("%d %d\n",result2,result1);
        System.out.printf("%.3f %.3f\n",product_arith,average_arith);

   }
}
```

So When I input example numbers everything checks out except overflow,

```
input: 100000 200000 300000 500000
```

Expected output:

```
-1679818752 275000

 3000000000000000000000.000 275000.000
```

My output:

```
-1679818752 275000

-1679818752.000 275000.000
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The result of multiplying two `int`s is an `int`. So here, you multiply the inputted numbers as `int`s (which causes them to overflow), and only then promote the result to a `double`. In order to get a non-overlowing result, you need to have at least one of the operands in each multiplication as a `double`. Since the `*` is left-associative, casting `num1` to a `double` should do the trick:

```java
double product_arith = ((double) num1) * num2 * num3 * num4;
-- Here ----------------^
```

Comment: It fixed the overflow issue but messed with the starting -1679818752.

Comment: @ErickGuerrero You should only do this for the second requirement. The first one explicitly calls for integer math and leaving the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this lab too!

Mureinik has it right BUT I made a second product variable just for the overflow, and used the first one for the int. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
  int average;
  average = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
  int product;
  product = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4;
  double product2;
  double average2;
  average2 = ((double)num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 / 4.0);
  product2 = ((double)num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int num3;
  int num4;

    num1 = scnr.nextInt();
    num2 = scnr.nextInt();
    num3 = scnr.nextInt();
    num4 = scnr.nextInt();

      int average;
      average = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
      int product;
      product = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4;
      double product2;
      double average2;
      average2 = ((double)num1 + num2 + num3 + num4);
      product2 = ((double)num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
      
      System.out.printf("%d %d\n", average, product);
    System.out.printf("%.3f %.3f\n", product2, average2 / 4.0 );
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.